# How to handle a professor disrupting workspace peace?

Tags: united-states, work-environment, difficult-people, rudeness

So I'm currently an international (Latin) grad student at some US university and wanted to know how to improve my current work space situation.

I share an office with another 2 Chinese grad students, that part is fine. Two professors access their offices going through ours and one of them is very "particular".

The issue is this, he is very impolite to all of us, when he comes out of his office he sometimes hits one of the other students desk and sometimes he does it so hard that things from his desk fall off, once he even hit the other student, and since he couldn't open immediately he continued to slam the door several times against him while he moved, not super hard but still..., he also plays music rather loud so even when his door is closed we can hear it very clear and he plays the same song for a loop all day long (the other day I learned that one of the songs he plays in a loop is the US national anthem).

All of that happens without a single word coming out of his mouth and he avoids eye contact with us.

Additional context, I'm a relatively new international student and he is an American tenured professor.

How can I improve our office current situation?

Comment: Hello and welcome to IPS, Pedrino! Have you spoken to the other students in your office about this behavior? It might make it easier to address it as a group, if it bothers them too.

Comment: Can you also give some more details of what you have done on this issue before posting on the forum?

Comment: In addition to the previous commenters, it might be nice to be a bit more clear on who you're planning to interact with. We can help you here with the behaviours you use when interacting with people, but who you're interacting with will have an influence on potential answers. Are you planning on taking this up with your fellow students first, on confronting the professor directly, or are you thinking of involving a third party (if so, who)? This is a choice you're going to have to make...

Comment: Hi @EmC, yes I have spoken to the other students, they think he is "hard to deal with" but they don't feel like it is an issue we must bring up because of his position and the fact that we are all relatively new grad students. I'll try and edit my question after reading the guidelines.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza I tried to talk to him once and asked him about the volume of the music, he seemed reasonable and agreed but after that it just keep happening anyway.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I honestly don't know, I guess that's part of my issue, the other students don't want to cause a fuss and I tried talking to him and it didn't work so... I guess I'll edit my question.